# Preventing Dupe Questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, best-practices

I've had a few duplicate questions in my day, but they're all because when I ask a question the original doesn't show up in the list of Related Questions. I make it a point to look under Related Questions so I can get my answer faster. As much as I enjoy getting reputation for good questions, when a good question is already asked, I prefer to have my answer than more reputation. What's odd is that some of my dupe questions have had titles that were very near duplicate titles as other questions.

What can I do to further ensure that my question is not a dupe?

Answer (score 3):

First thing is to ask Google:

```
http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site:http://stackoverflow.com+your+question+title
```

Then ask Stack Overflow:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=your+title+[some]+[tags]
```

If neither of those reveal any duplicate questions, then I'd say you did your best.

As random pointed out, you should probably at least check the first 2 pages of results at least.

Comment: Then another user comes along, uses the same queries and finds it on page two. Bam! A dupe is found. Proceed to auto-comment.

Comment: @random, yeah, going beyond page 1 is far too much work.